# Window.open - size - multiple monitors

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, size

I am trying to open new window from a lightning component using **window.open**

I want to center this new window in the middle of the screen.

for this I am using this code :

```
var myWidth= 600;
        var myHeight=window.innerHeight;
        var left = (screen.width - myWidth )/ 2;
        var top = (screen.height - myHeight) ;

window.open('https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/','_blank','height='+myHeight+',width='+myWidth+',left='+left);
```

This work well when I open the window from my laptop screen but not at all when I open it from an other monitor.

what can I do to make sure this new window will always appear in the middle of the screen , no matter the size of the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this post out, should have the answer you are looking for:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068373/center-a-popup-window-on-screen